# Compare documents and remove duplication in Spark and Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Suppose i have these documents and i want to remove duplication :

```
buy sansa view sell product player charger world charge player charger receive 
oldest daughter teen daughter player christmas so daughter life line listen sooo hold
thourghly sansa view delete song time wont wont connect-computer computer put time 
oldest daughter teen daughter player christmas so daughter life line listen sooo hold
oldest daughter teen daughter player christmas so daughter life line listen sooo hold
```

this is output:

```
buy sansa view sell product player charger world charge player charger receive 
oldest daughter teen daughter player christmas so daughter life line listen sooo hold
thourghly sansa view delete song time wont wont connect-computer computer put time
```

is there any solution for this in Scala and Spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be reading the files on a line-wise basis so `textFile` will correctly read this into an RDD of strings, one row per line. After this, `distinct` will slim the RDD to a unique set.

```
sc.textFile("yourfile.txt")
  .distinct
  .saveAsTextFile("distinct.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the reduceByKey function, you can achieve your requirement.

You can use this code

```
val textFile = spark.textFile("hdfs://...")
val uLine = textFile.map(line => (line, 1))
                 .reduceByKey(_ + _).map(uLine => uLine._1)
uLine.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://...")
```

or you can use

```
val uLine = spark.textFile("hdfs://...").distinct
uLine.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://...")
```